# Setting ScrollView background colour programmatically

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am fairly new to Android.
While using below code to set background colour for ScrollView I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference"

```
        ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.content_scroll);
    scroll.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

However when I use it with TextView it works fine.

```
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,mSetColor);

    TextView textContent = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    textContent.setText(mCurrentContent.getmTextContent());
    textContent.setBackgroundColor(color);
    textContent.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
```

Below is the complete code, seems like I am missing on something basic.

```
package com.example.android.tourguide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ContentAdapter {

private Content mCurrentContent;
public View mRootView;
private int mSetColor;
private Context mContext;

public ContentAdapter(Content content, View rootView, int setColor,Context context) {
    mRootView = rootView;
    mCurrentContent = content;
    mSetColor = setColor;
    mContext= context;

}

public View setContent() {


    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,mSetColor);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setImageResource(mCurrentContent.getmImageResourceID());

    TextView imageText = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.image_description);
    imageText.setText(mCurrentContent.getmImageDescriptionText());

    TextView textContent = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.content);
    textContent.setText(mCurrentContent.getmTextContent());
    textContent.setBackgroundColor(color);
    textContent.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.content_scroll);
    scrollView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return mRootView;

    }

}
```

Complete XML Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contentView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary_light"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="abc"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0" />


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="abc"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop"
            />

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Output
[Need to fill the white space below green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho5GZ.png)

Comment: `int color` is null probably

Comment: Where do you set `mRootView`? Because it can't find your view with that id in the parent `mRootView`

Comment: where is main View layout ?? show full code

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya An int cannot be null (Integer can be). And if you read the exception again it says it cannot call the method `setBackgroundColor(int)` because the view is null.

Comment: @Denny yes yes .User didn't call layout

Comment: Surprisingly if I set the colour for Scroll View in XML, that also doesn't show up when I run the app. Though, colour does show up in XML preview. I have added the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you when i use `ScrollView`, my layout xml would be like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
    >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Small"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop"
        android:text="abc"
        />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView must has a child layout. Then i will set the color on the LinearLayout for your case:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(your color);
```

Comment: Thanks, but issue is still the same. Tried keeping Linear Layout outside of scrollview as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ContentAdapter(Content content, View rootView, int setColor,Context context) {mSetColor = setColor; }
```

Cheak once you are sending color from Activity to **ContentAdapter** Constructor set color is getting null so you get nullpointerException

Comment: Poor answer, in fact it doesn't answer the question at all because an int cannot be null.

Comment: No it's not getting null because TextView is able to set colour successfully with the same variable.